# Getting columns from more than 2 tables and then inserting them into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I wrote some code to try and fetch multiple columns from different tables and join them together before inserting them into an array. It works when I was doing it on single tables, and two different tables, but when I tried to do it for three tables, suddenly I'm getting more results than I'm suppose to. A lot more. Please take a look:

```
include('connect.php');
```

> $arrayX = "pieces.pieceID,playerDeck.amount,playerPieces.amount/pieces,
>   playerDeck,playerPieces/where playerDeck.playerName = 'playerName' and
>   playerPieces.playerName = 'playerName' and pieces.name =
>   playerDeck.name = playerPieces.name";

```
$arrayX = explode('/', $arrayX);
$column = $arrayX[0];
$table = $arrayX[1];
$where = $arrayX[2];

$myArray = explode(',', $column);

global $connect;
$fetch = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT $column FROM $table $where");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($fetch);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch,MYSQLI_NUM)){

  $count --;
  $arrayCount = count($myArray);

  while($arrayCount > 0){
  $arrayCount--;
  $array[$count][$arrayCount]= $row[$arrayCount];
  }

}

$count = count($array);
echo $count." rows";
```

Expected output:

```
32 rows
```

Actual output:

```
31744 rows
```

31,744/32 = 922. Which means I got 922 of the same copies of the rows I needed. I have no idea just what I did wrong to get 922 copies, nor how is that actually even possible. If anyone can figure out just what I did wrong, please point it out. Thank you very much.

Comment: This looks suspicious: `and pieces.name = playerDeck.name = playerPieces.name`

Comment: i think frosty is injecting his own sql, attacking himself

Comment: @DrewPierce c'mon where did I inject anything at all?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It worked fine when I did it for this string: "username1,username2,username3/test1,test2,test3/where test1.id = test2.id = test3.id"

Comment: To ask the obvious, did you inspect the output to see what it looks like?  It may be that the logic in the query is flawed.

Comment: frosty i was just being funny bud :)

Comment: you should consider normalizing your tables. Means you have player table and the other tables have a foreign key player_id. Then you can easily join the tables together

Comment: Hey just want to point out that the `col = col = col` syntax is valid, at least it appears to be. Check out sample here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/9686

Comment: @MarkM Hey if it's valid how come when I changed it, it suddenly worked?

Comment: I have no idea, @frosty. I didn't think it would work, but when I tested it, sure enough, it did. I could be missing something, though. The link to the sample fiddle is the only evidence I have. Try changing the where statement to `1 = 1 = 0` and it will return 0 records, because it's a false statement. This tells me that SQL allows for this type of cascading comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing c4pone's answer, before it was deleted, I tried to edit that part where it said it was breaking it? And then it worked.

```
$arrayX = "pieces.pieceID,playerDeck.amount,playerPieces.amount/pieces,playerDeck,playerPieces/where playerDeck.playerName = 'playerName' and playerPieces.playerName = 'playerName' and pieces.name = playerDeck.name and pieces.name = playerPieces.name";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
pieces p INNER JOIN playerDeck pd
ON p.name = pd.name
INNER JOIN playerPieces pp
ON pd.name = pp.name
WHERE pd.playerName = 'playerName' AND
pp.playerName = 'playerName'
```

If you get 31744 rows, the you will know that the logic in your query is not quite what you expected.

Comment: i think Tim is dead on. completely ignore the while loop. echo $count right before while and stop/fix.

Answer (score 0):

Cartesian product?

You try writing the query with "Inner Join".

Just like that:

```
pieces p INNER JOIN playerDeck pd
ON p.name = pd.name
INNER JOIN playerPieces pp
ON pd.name = pp.name
WHERE pd.playerName = 'playerName' AND
pp.playerName = 'playerName'
```